# Use JQuery Mobile to slide and delete list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm experimenting with a JQuery Mobile page that has a simple list set up:

[image: page]

When I click the list elements, they are highlighted and stored by id into a local array. Is there a simple (or not so simple) way to make the selected elements slide to the right off the screen and the rest of the elements collapse to fill the gaps?

Relevant code:

```
var selectedItems = []; // This is updated as items are selected

var deleteButtonTapped = function() {
    // code here
};
```

Edit: If it is of any pertinence, in the actual implementation of the page, the items that I am populating the list with will be drawn from a database, so I will be able to reload the page and the deleted elements will no longer appear.

Comment: Totally possible, check out the [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) documentation.

Comment: Do you need to be able to recall the removed elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKpRD/4/) - This is close to what you are looking for...
using `.animate()`

EDIT: Adding code...

The `.animate()` function is saying, if the elements left property is 0, then move it to the right as many pixels as it is wide, then hiding it using the `.fadeOut()` function. This same formula can also be used to slide the element back into place if needed.

HTML

```
<ul id="list" data-role="listview">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
<button id='btnDelete'>Delete</button>
```

CSS

```
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('yellow'); 
});

$('#btnDelete').click(function(){
    $('.yellow').each(function(){
       $(this).animate({ marginLeft: parseInt($(this).css('marginLeft'),10) === 0 ?   $(this).outerWidth() : 0 }).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: pls add some explanation as to what your fiddle is abt. this way if your your fiddle is gone , the code wil still be here. you'll get my +1 i you do that ;)

Comment: You just got yourself a +1 ;-)